# S3 URL issue when re generating the signed URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am using S3 bucket for storing the images of my app. When I am uploading the images to it for the first time I am generating a signed URL which is in the below pattern:

```
https://app-images.s3.amazonaws.com/test/-26403.blob?AWSAccessKeyId=<key>&Expires=<timestamp>&Signature=<signature>
```

Observe that there is no region code in the above URL. As the URL expiry time is 7 days, I am regenerating the signed URL before expiry. And this time the URL pattern is like below.

```
https://app-images.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/-26403.blob?AWSAccessKeyId=<key>&Expires=<timestamp>&Signature=<signature>
```

Observe that there is region code in above URL.
With this URL when I try to render these images on the browser it was giving CORB issue. But when I removed the region code from above URL and render it in browser, it is working.

Both the times, I am using the same function to generate the signed URL which is as below.

```js
const getFileUrl = async (payload) => {
    let params = {
        Bucket: s3BucketName,
        Key: `${payload.folderName}/${payload.fileName}`,
        Expires: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
    };
    
    try {
        const url = await s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
        return { url, fileName: payload.fileName };
    } catch (e) {
        return Boom.badRequest(e.message);
    }
};
```

My concern is I don't want to have inconsistency in URL. Both the times the URL pattern should be same and it should render properly in browser.

Can someone help me to achieve this?

Comment: I am confused. You say "When I am uploading the images to it for the first time", but the code appears to be generating a URL for **downloading** objects (`getObject`). Do you have separate used to general pre-signed URLs for uploads and downloads?

Comment: For uploading there is a separate code. The code i mentioned above is only used for generating signed urls after uploading the file and also for regenerating the signed url.

Comment: So, the fact that you are using different code might explain why the URLs came back a bit different.

Comment: Not different code, It's the same code for generating signed url. For uploading it is different. But even after uploading i am calling the above mentioned function to generate signed url. So ultimately same function is being used to generate signed url.